# macro to import website table(s) into excel

Tags: database, excel, web, vba

Im really new to all things coding (academic/psychologist) and Im trying to pull the data from this site to create my [own local database](https://register.fca.org.uk/ShPo_Homepage).

My method (I cant find a "list all" features) has been to query the UK postcode district i.e. AB1, [see here](https://register.fca.org.uk/shpo_searchresultspage?search=AB1&TOKEN=3wq1nht7eg7tr) using the code i compiled from a few sources (see below) in VBA.

```
Sub GetCourseList()

Dim URL As String
Dim qt As QueryTable
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets.Add

URL = "https://register.fca.org.uk/shpo_searchresultspage?search=AB1&TOKEN=3wq1nht7eg7tr"

Set qt = ws.QueryTables.Add( _
    Connection:="URL;" & URL, _
    Destination:=Range("A1"))

With qt
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = True
    .Name = "CoursesFromWiseOwl"
    .FieldNames = True
    .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

End Sub
```

my issues are 3 fold:

1. I want to repeat this for all 3000-odd UK postcode districts (I can get a list)
2. I want to remove the extra lines it returns (if you run the code 1-22 and
   548+, but this will differ per district)
3. I'd like to compile all the data to 1 database, not 3000 separate sheets.

the excel getdata/webquery/table 1 (using [this URL](https://register.fca.org.uk/shpo_searchresultspage?search=AB1&TOKEN=3wq1nht7eg7tr) does almost exactly what I want, except it only returns page 1, but I haven't been able to work out how to automate/stitch the code I want together!

can anyone help sort this out for me?

cheers

Seb

ps sorry forgot to add the reason I'm not grabbing directly from direct pages is the use of 2 different types of personal page (see below) that don't seem to have any predictable method of ID generation in the URL. I'll be writing a second query to scan the FCA numbers in the same fashion to populate a 2nd database with more complete data.

(register.fca.org.uk/ShPo_FirmDetailsPage?id=001b000000MfTlAAAV and

fca-consumer-credit-interim.force.com/CS_RegisterSearchPageNew?accId=210552)

Answer (score 0):

The script below will do the looping for you.  I'll leave it to you to do the cleanup.  Hint, hint...use the Macro Recorder.

```
Sub GetCourseList()

Dim URL As String
Dim qt As QueryTable
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets.Add

Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

variable = 1
Here:
URL = "https://register.fca.org.uk/shpo_searchresultspage?search=AB" & variable & "&TOKEN=3wq1nht7eg7tr"

lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set qt = ws.QueryTables.Add( _
    Connection:="URL;" & URL, _
    Destination:=Range("A" & lastRow))

With qt
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = True
    .Name = "CoursesFromWiseOwl"
    .FieldNames = True
    .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

variable = variable + 1
GoTo Here:

End Sub
```

The last thing I'll say is that R will do this much, much, much faster for you.  If I were you, I'd use R for this kind of stuff.

https://www.r-bloggers.com/search/web%20scraping/